# Using Wordpress' wp_is_mobile() function to serve alternate page templates

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering whether it is possible to use the wp_is_mobile() function to serve up a prefixed "mobile-" version of a themes page templates, or some other similar technique? For example:

```
function mobile_template() {
    if( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        // Look for template being used by page and switch
        // out for same template with mobile- prefix
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will mess with the template hierarchy or anything, but it just seems like a relatively simple approach for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes . `wp_is_mobile()` is a conditional function that checks if a user is using a mobile device or not . Returns TRUE or FALSE. Hence - it is actually made for exactly the scenario you are refering to in your question .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's simple approach but it will miss the when you are using the cache for you website. As this will check on server side not user side.